# Android webview change highlight color of the link

Tags: android, webview, highlight

I need to change the default selection color of the link in Android webview.
Going through the few questions in the stack overflow didn't help me .
Below question answer how to remove it. I want to just change the color from orange to e.g. red.
[Android browser GREEN border on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728566/android-browser-green-border-on-click)

Can some one help me out ?

Comment: Seeking for the same answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind getting jQuery involved (I never do), first add this:

```
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);  
}
```

Then use the `touchstart` or `touchend` commands like this:

```
$("li").bind('touchstart', function(){
    $(this).css("border","1px solid green");
    setTimeout("$('li').css('border','none')",1500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change it in WebView. You can however read the data as a string, replace all a tags by (lt)font color="#0000FF"(gt)(lt)a (and change the /a tags accordingly) and then load the string in WebView with webView.loadData(String string ..).